# jQuery rotate through multiple tickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ticker

So I have 3 news tickers that I want to display at the top of a page.
(Sidenote: these aren't for a website, they're a part of a bigger internal marketing display for my company. The page will only be loaded one time, and then will sit on a quad 70 inch TV display forever)

I'm trying to rotate between these tickers. I want to go from the first one, to the second, to the third, and restart that. All of this has to happen AFTER the ticker has rotated through all the li's within it.

I came up with a way to get from the first to the second ticker, but can't get past that.

```
 if (tick1.css('opacity') == '1')
    setTimeout(function() {
      tick1.hide();
      tick2.show();
    }, $('.tick1 ul li').length * 1000);
```

NOTE: in the fiddle below, my js starts on line 222. All other js is provided by Aakash Chakravarthy.

https://jsfiddle.net/3yhaynpz/2/

Comment: You should really not depend your code on timing like you are doing. You should rather add a callback to the code supplied by Aakash Chakravarthy, that will tell you when to cycle to the next "headline".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something you're looking for?

```
var tickers = ['.tick1','.tick2','.tick3'];

for(var i=0;i<tickers.length;i++){

    (function(i){

      var $currentTicker = $(tickers[i]);
      var $nextTicker;

      if(i==tickers.length-1)
        $nextTicker= $(tickers[0]);
      else 
        $nextTicker= $(tickers[i+1]);


      setTimeout(function() {
          $currentTicker.hide();
          $nextTicker.show();
      },$currentTicker.find('ul li').length * 1000 * (i+1));

    })(i);
}
```

Code above cycles through all your tickers and is not limited to 3. You can add how many tickers you want in that array. You can also clear your previous `timeout` before starting a new one.

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3yhaynpz/5/)

**EDIT**:  Fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3yhaynpz/6/) for infinite loop

Comment: This doesn't work as the Question asker wanted; it doesn't loop back to the beginning.

Comment: Look at that fiddle. It starts from the first element once it has reached the end.

Comment: Ok. Check your code btw. It's not working. You're blocking the ui thread.

Comment: I am? Oops, thanks. That's probably why it's running really badly (or it's my computer again).

Comment: Beautiful. Both answers work, but this one doesn't increase in size if I were to add more tickers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2023469 I think you mean mine doesn't increase in size.

Comment: @Kosmo I think the looping is still messed up (and also the code in your answer doesn't reflect the changes to the fiddle). It only loops once because you only reset the currentTicker once.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 Like I said, the answer that Kosmo provided does not increase in size if I were to add another ticker, so that is why I accepted this answer. This snippet loops correctly in chrome.

Comment: @user2023469/RonnieEXP Oh, sorry, I thought you meant that it had to be changed if the amount of tickers are changed (which is the case with mine), my bad.

Comment: @RonnieEXP I added another fiddle for an infinite looping mechanism of same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your code with this, so that it checks to see if the tick is hidden, and if not, it will start the timeout for cycling it. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8a8dd7z/)

```
cycle();
function cycle(){
    if (tick1.css('display') !== 'none')
      setTimeout(function() {
        tick1.hide();
        tick2.show();
        cycle();
      }, $('.tick1 ul li').length * 1000);

    else if (tick2.css('display') !== 'none')
      setTimeout(function() {
        tick2.hide();
        tick3.show();
        cycle();
      }, $('.tick2 ul li').length * 1000);

    else if (tick3.css('display') !== 'none')
      setTimeout(function() {
        tick3.hide();
        tick1.show();
        cycle();
      }, $('.tick3 ul li').length * 1000);
}
```